# I have a many poppers and want the one that is open to close when another one opens

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a component experience that creates 6 experience and each experience has a popper with images. I want to be able to close the popper that was opened if another popper is clicked on but I am lost on how to change my code to do this..

This is my component

```
 */const Experiences = memo(
  (props) => {
    const { className } = props;
    const classes = useStyles(props);

    const [poperOpen, setPoperOpen] = React.useState([]); // array of popers states
    const [justChange, setJustChange] = useState(false); // array of popers states

    // one handle click for open/close
    const handleClick = (e, _id, _open) => {
      const idx = poperOpen.findIndex(x => x.id === _id);
      const a = poperOpen;
      if (idx > -1) {
        a.splice(idx, 1);
      }
      a.push({ id: _id, open: _open, anchorEl: e.currentTarget });

      setPoperOpen(a);
      setJustChange(!justChange);
    };

    const experience = (img, title, id, popoverCategory) => (
      <div>
        <div
          className="experience"
          aria-describedby={id}
          id={id}
          onClick={e => handleClick(e, id, true)}
          onKeyDown={e => handleClick(e, id, true)}
          role="button"
          tabIndex="0"
        >
          <img
            data-sizes="auto"
            className="lazyload"
            data-src={img}
            alt={title}
          />
          <div className="experience-title">
            <Typography
              color="textSecondary"
              variant="subtitle2"
              className="highlight highlight1"
              display="inline"
            >
              { title }
            </Typography>
          </div>
        </div>

        <Popper
          id={id}
          open={poperOpen.findIndex(x => x.id === id) > -1 && poperOpen.find(x => x.id === id).open}
          anchorEl={poperOpen.findIndex(x => x.id === id) > -1
            ? poperOpen.find(x => x.id === id).anchorEl : undefined}
          className={clsx(classes[id])}
          modifiers={{
            flip: {
              enabled: false,
            },
          }}
        >
          <Button onClick={e => handleClick(e, id, false)}>x</Button>
          <div className={clsx(classes.paper)}>
            {
              popoverCategory.map(url => (

                <img
                  key={id}
                  data-sizes="auto"
                  className="lazyload"
                  src={url}
                  alt={title}
                />
              ))
            }
          </div>
        </Popper>
      </div>

    );
```

I need to change this

```
const [poperOpen, setPoperOpen] = React.useState([]);
```

for something like this I think

const [poperOpen, setPoperOpen] = React.useState(null);

but when I do this I get an error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'findIndex' of null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way is to **mutate the previous state** of the `poperOpen` array and not modifying directly as you did in your code when using `a` variable which is technically `poperOpen`'s reference still.

Find here a possible working solution for `handleClick`:

```
const handleClick = (e, _id, _open) => {
  setPoperOpen(prevArray => {
     const idx = prevArray.findIndex(x => x.id === _id);
     const a = [...prevArray];
     if (idx > -1) {
        a.splice(idx, 1);
     }
     a.push({ id: _id, open: _open, anchorEl: e.currentTarget });
     return a;
  });

  setJustChange(!justChange);
};
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can manually close all the Poppers inside your handleClick method, and just open the correct one.

```
const handleClick = (e, _id, _open) => {
  const idx = poperOpen.findIndex(x => x.id === _id);
  const a = poperOpen;
  a.forEach((part, index) => {
    a[index].open = false;
  });
  ...
};
```